# Linking to a specific tab / contentpane with Dojo

Tags: html, hyperlink, dojo, tabs, tabcontainer

I want to navigate from a link on a html site to another where a TabContainer with two different tabs is located.

I have one tab selected by default (which I want to keep) in the destination html file.

How do I have to put the link so that this is working? I found several documents on the net but nothing works. So probably someone needs to explain this to me the dumb way.

Here is the destination TabContainer:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center" tabStrip="true">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Contact" selected="true">
some text
</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Imprint" selected="true">
some text
</div>
```

I want to place a link to autmatically be navigated to the title "Imprint".

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot and all the best
TTP

Answer (score 0):

You can either select it from javascript, or generate the markup for the tab from your server with the `selected` attribute to `true` (you'll need to set the other to `false`). This second alternative, depends on your server technology.

For the first option, add ids to the container and tabs and select the tab when the page finished loading. Something like:

```
<div id="tabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center" tabStrip="true">
  <div id="tab1" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Contact" selected="true">
    some text
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Imprint" selected="false">
    some text
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  dojo.ready(function() {
    dijit.byId('tabContainer').selectChild(dijit.byId('tab2'));
  });
</script>
```

If you want to dynamically select either tab, you'll need to pass some kind of parameter in the URL to your page. You can use a query parameter (variables after the `?` symbol) or a hash fragment (anything after `#`). Query parameter you can read both from the server and from javascript. Hash fragments, only from javascript.

You can access those parameters by inspecting the [`location`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) object. For example, using a hash fragment, you'd link to your page like `http://host/page.html#imprint`. Then in the `<script>` tag above:

```
<script>
  dojo.ready(function() {
    if (location.hash == '#imprint') {
      dijit.byId('tabContainer').selectChild(dijit.byId('tab2'));
    }
  });
</script>
```

For query parameters, also see [`dojo.queryToObject()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojo#dojo.queryToObject).

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great when I put the code on the site. But I wan to navigate to the tab from a completely different html site. Can I pass the information to the script in some way?

Comment: Edited the answer to include your inquiry.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot and saved me a grand amount of time! Very, very helpful! Thanks again!